# Cloudflare Heroku Express.js SSL

Tags: express, ssl, heroku, https, cloudflare

I am using Cloudflare, Heroku Hobby Dynos to host my website. I am quite confused on how https and SSL management is being handled using their provided SSL certificates. Should I purchase my own self signed certificate instead?

Also on the backend, I have it currently configured with http, but since I did not manually purchase an SSL cert but rather using Heroku's and/or Cloudflare's, what should I do to handle https requests with the `https` library?

Here is what I currently have:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = require('socket.io')(server);
require('./socket')(io);

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(chalk.blue('Server started on port', chalk.magenta(PORT)));
});
```